# Currency cells and PHPSpreadsheet: How to read the currency from it?

Tags: phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I have an Excel (XLSX) file with a column containing values in different currencies, e.g. "CAD 4711.00", "NOK 56.78", "CHF 123.45".

[image]

Now I try to read data from these cells and I just cannot get the currencies. The best I can do is get the value (4711, 56.78, 123.45) but I also need to figure out which currency the cell is in. How can I do this?

I would be relatively happy if I could just get the formatted value but I do not see a way to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps to get started :

```
$fileExcel          = 'mony.xlsx';
$reader             = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet        = $reader->load($fileExcel);
$sheet              = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$lsValue            = $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
$lsFormat           = $sheet->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
echo $lsValue .':'. $lsFormat .'<HR>';
```

the result is something like that:

```
123:#,##0.00\ "€"
123.12:#,##0.00\ [$EUR] 
3123:#,##0.00\ [$₽-444]
```

split the format and inspect it further for your currency